# Is there a way to transfer Jetpack joyride profiles from iphone to android?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

I had a pretty solid profile with a few purchases on my ipod. have since upgraded to android. anyway to transfer my profile?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure Jetpack Joyride uses OpenFeint services. If you had an OpenFeint profile made from your iPod and you log into it with your Android, it should transfer fine.

Comment: I think openFeint is for scores only. But I could be wrong.

Comment: OpenFeint is dead, closed down, deceased. Most iOS games released patches that removed OpenFeint support a long time ago.